# Error with SubSonic 2.0.3

Tags: .net, subsonic

I have to work on an application which used Subsonic 2.0.3. When I opened the project,I got a message

The projectfile 'C:\Program Files\Subsonic\Subsonic 2.0.3\src\SubSonic\SubSonic.csproj' has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer.

Does it mean I need to install Subsonic 2.0.3, I tried to find the same version but could not find it. Can I download the next version 'Setup-SubSonic-2.1'  Does Subsonic 2.1 provide compatability with 2.0.3 ?

Regards
Sbmarya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are opening up a solution that includes a project called SubSonic.  It would be best to ask the person who used to maintain the application you are working on for his copy of SubSonic 2.0.3 (because he might have made some changes to it).  If that is not possible, grab the source from the SubSonic site and replace the SubSonic project in your solution with the one your just downloaded.

And yes, SubSonic 2.1 should be mostly compatible with 2.0.3.

P.S.  You don't need to put the SubSonic source in the Program Files directory.  It probably would be best to move the source to a folder within your solution's folder to everything together.

Also, another thing you can try is to grab the pre-built SubSonic dll's and reference those in your application instead of including the SubSonic project source.